# Find all entire functions such that $|f(z)| \leqslant 4|z|^{\frac{7}{3}}+2$ for all $|z| \geqslant 10$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all entire functions such that $|f(z)| \leqslant 4|z|^{\frac{7}{3}}+2$ for all $|z| \geqslant 10$. I can show that this must be a polynomial of order at most 2. Then what is next?

Normally it would be natural to use the condition to find the zeros of $f$, but I do not know how to do that here.

Comment: that's a pretty strange condition

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but very close http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974564/does-there-exist-a-non-constant-entire-function-f-such-that-fz3-leq-1

Comment: I doubt it is enough to say that it is a polynomial of order at most 2 in this case.

Comment: The Cauchy estimates give you bounds for the coefficients. But not all combinations of coefficients satisfying the individual constraints will give a polynomial having the given global bound. Things would of course be simple if the exponent was $\frac{3}{7}$ rather than $\frac{7}{3}$. Maybe a typo.